# How to adjust a QSlider's handle?

Tags: c++, qt, qslider

I'm writing an app for a touchscreen, and the default handle is too small to grab reliably, so I want to make it bigger.  According to the official documentation, several answers on SE, and a couple of other forums, this ought to work in a QWidget's constructor:

```
sliderGrandMaster = new QSlider(Qt::Vertical, panelRight);
sliderGrandMaster->setGeometry(          appdata->buttonBorder ,    //Left
                   buttonTopRight +      appdata->buttonBorder ,    //Top
                        halfwidth - (2 * appdata->buttonBorder),    //Width
            buttonRemainingHeight - (2 * appdata->buttonBorder));   //Height
sliderGrandMaster->setRange(0, RANGE_MAX);
sliderGrandMaster->setTickInterval(RANGE_MAX / 10);
sliderGrandMaster->setTickPosition(QSlider::TicksBothSides);
QString temp =  QString("handle:vertical { background: green; height: %1px; margin: 0 -%2px; }")
                .arg(buttonRemainingHeight / 5)
                .arg(halfwidth / 3);
sliderGrandMaster->setStyleSheet(temp);
```

But it seems to have no effect.  The handle is the same small size regardless of what values I put in the stylesheet, and it's not even green.

With my values at runtime, `temp` ends up being `handle:vertical { background: green; height: 66px; margin: 0 -32px; }`.  The size of the slider is `94px wide by 331px tall`.

Am I missing something?

---

### Edit:

This:

```
QString temp =  QString("QSlider::handle { background: green; height: %1px; width: %1px; margin: 0 -%2px; }")
                .arg(buttonRemainingHeight / 5)
                .arg(halfwidth / 3);
sliderGrandMaster->setStyleSheet(temp);
```

at least got it green.  But the size is still wrong.  Qt version 5.4.2

Comment: Did you miss `QSlider::handle:vertical` in your style sheet? From https://forum.qt.io/topic/36346/solved-qslider-handle-size-after-stylesheet/5, but more information here http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider.

Comment: @maxik  `temp = "QSlider::handle:vertical { <identical contents> }"` doesn't work either.

Comment: Which Qt version do you use?

Comment: @maxik  Added some new info, including the version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, using Qt 5.6.1 I got some progress on this. The following code

```
QSlider* slider = new QSlider(this);
slider->setOrientation(Qt::Horizontal);
slider->setStyleSheet("QSlider::groove:horizontal { "
                      "border: 1px solid #999999; "
                      "height: 20px; "
                      "background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 #B1B1B1, stop:1 #c4c4c4); "
                      "margin: 2px 0; "
                      "} "
                      "QSlider::handle:horizontal { "
                      "background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 #b4b4b4, stop:1 #8f8f8f); "
                      "border: 1px solid #5c5c5c; "
                      "width: 30px; "
                      "margin: -2px 0px; "
                      "} ");

QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
layout->addWidget(slider);
layout->addWidget(new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal, this));
setLayout(layout);
```

may be placed into an emty `QWidget` to work. It simply adds two `QSliders`, one of which is modified using a style sheet.

As you may see, I used to change the groove too and it is working *as intended*. But there are strange issues which could be a bug at all. Try commenting out some properties of the groove style sheet, like *border*, *background* and *margin*. If there are no effective properties, the *width* property of the handle is dropped. As I cannot find any constraint in the documentation, I wonder why this happens.

Also note the issues drawing the *border* around the handle. Seems to need some more fine tuning. ;)

[image: screenshot of sliders]

---

Summing things up the quick solution for you should be added some default properties for the groove.

Comment: Looks like that worked.  Required parameters for a vertical slider are `groove.background`, `groove.width`, `handle.background`, `handle.height`, and `handle.margin`.  Thanks!

Comment: You might accept an answer then, two correct so far ;) It still puzzles me, this behaviour... strange. I should dig into that.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the size of the handle just with a simple stylesheet. Example :

[image: QSlider]

Is done with the following stylesheet :

```
QSlider::groove:horizontal
{
    border:none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}  

QSlider::sub-page
{
    background: rgb(164, 192, 2);
}

QSlider::add-page 
{
    background: rgb(70, 70, 70);
}

QSlider::handle
{
    background: white;
    border: 3px solid black;
    width: 60px; // **Change the width here**
    margin: -30px 0;
}
```

Comment: The height and width ratio in the style sheet doesn't seem to match the picture's. Anyway, this should be the whole solution.

Comment: @maxik  I've never seen an actual example of how to use that format.  It's always been loose code like is presented here.  How do I add it to an existing (and somewhat large) project?

Comment: @AaronD You do already in your provided code... may I quote you: `sliderGrandMaster->setStylesheet(...);`. Place the content inside the brakets or put it there using a `QString` or something. For further readings http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html.

Comment: @maxik  Okay, I guess the formatting is throwing me off.  It's often formatted like C++ code itself with multiple lines and indentation and highlighting, so it looks like it should be compiled somehow instead of interpreted at runtime.  Nevertheless, I tried including the `QSlider::` bit as well, to fully specify it, and that doesn't work either.

Comment: @maxik it is because of the margins, I just noticed that the height actually has no effect.

Comment: @dydil May you confirm that your width is working properly?

Comment: @maxik I didn't precisely count the pixel, but it is about the same size as a 60px wide button above it and it changes when the width is changed.